# SQL to calculate sum of column values and repeat this value over all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
COL1    COL2
ABC     1
DEF     2
GHI     3
```

And I want to have the sum of COL2 in a new column COL3:

```
COL1    COL2   COL3
ABC     1      6
DEF     2      6
GHI     3      6
```

So taking a simple sum won't work because it will return only 1 value, whereas I want the value to be repeated over all rows.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: It is in MySQL.

Comment: Try my Updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  ,(SELECT SUM(Col2) FROM Your_Table) Col3 
FROM Your_Table
```

Try this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
  ,SUM(Col2) OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) Col3 
FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: It's only returning me 1 row with the sum for some reason

Comment: @vdvaxel, I can't understand what the actual problem to you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify a dbms, this should work in most (all?) dbms's (tested in sql server):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(3), Col2 INT)

INSERT @T (Col1, Col2)
VALUES ( 'ABC' , 1  )
,       ('DEF', 2)
,       ('GHI', 3)  

SELECT  *
FROM    @T
CROSS JOIN (
                SELECT SUM(T.Col2) Col3
                FROM    @T AS T
            ) X
```

Comment: Is it not possible without a JOIN? (in MySQL)

Comment: Why do you not want to use a join?

Comment: What if the numbers that I would like to sum are not in a table but in a different subquery? It doesn't seem to work then. For example, `(SELECT ID FROM ...) x` and then `CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(x.ID))`. It says 'x' is an unknown table...

Comment: Well no, that wouldn't work. You can't use a table in the outer query in a subquery that way. What are you really trying to do? I have the feeling you are overcomplicating things. By the way, Dinesh' answer should be perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

Though you didn't mention the `Server Tag` for `SQL`, I resolved it using `MYSQL` Server. Try this in MYSQL Server:

```
Select t.Col1, t.Col2, t1.Col3 from tbl as t join (Select Sum(Col2) as Col3 from tbl) as t1
```

See the demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/602545/9)

Comment: Now what if I have a subquery where I need to select the SUM from, instead of a separate table 'tbl' in your example. Would that still work? Btw I'm using MySQL

Comment: @vdvaxel yeah. You can `select Sum(columname) from anyTable` in the parenthesis. Just alise it as t1.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add the two columns you have to perform the joins query. Base on your operation rather you have to perform inner join or outer join .For more description you can see the respective databases

Comment: Is it not possible without a join?

Comment: where exactly do you want to use it in android or other platform?