# MySQL combining COUNT, MAX and SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

In MySQL, I would like to have an extra column showing the sum of values of a particular column. However, the numbers I would like to sum come from a subquery and are not stored in a separate table, something like this:

```
(SELECT a.ID, MAX(a.COUNT_ID) AS MAX_COUNT FROM
    (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_ID
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY COL1, COL2) a
 GROUP BY COL1, COL2) b
```

And this would output something like:

```
ID     MAX_COUNT
ABC    1
DEF    2
GHI    3
```

And now, I want an extra column showing the sum of MAX_COUNT, like this (repeated over all rows):

```
ID     MAX_COUNT    SUM_MAX_COUNT
ABC    1            6
DEF    2            6
GHI    3            6
```

The actual goal is actually to show the percentage MAX_COUNT of the total MAX_COUNT, so 1/6, 2/6 and 3/6.
How do I do this? I already tried doing a `CROSS JOIN` but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM
    ((SELECT a.ID, MAX(a.COUNT_ID) AS MAX_COUNT FROM
        (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_ID
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY COL1, COL2) a
     GROUP BY COL1, COL2) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(b.MAX_COUNT)) AS c
```

Error: Unknown table 'b'

---

**EXAMPLE**

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
COL1 varchar(255),
COL2 varchar(255),
DAY int,
HOUR int);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
('X','Y',1,12),
('X','Y',1,13),
('X','Y',1,13),
('A','B',2,19),
('X','B',3,13),
('X','B',3,13);
```

Now I want to have, for each combination of COL1 and COL2, the number of lines in this table for each hour:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, HOUR, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_LINES
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY DAY, HOUR, COL1, COL2;
```

Which outputs this:

```
COL1    COL2    HOUR    COUNT_LINES
X       Y       12      1
X       Y       13      2
A       B       19      1
X       B       13      2
```

Now I want, for each combination of COL1 and COL2, the maximum of COUNT_LINES, so I use the query above in a subquery:

```
SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, MAX(a.COUNT_LINES)
FROM 
    (SELECT COL1, COL2, HOUR, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_LINES
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY DAY, HOUR, COL1, COL2) a
GROUP BY COL1, COL2;
```

Which outputs this:

```
COL1    COL2    MAX(COUNT_LINES)
A       B       1
X       B       2
X       Y       2
```

Now in the last step, I want the SUM of MAX(COUNT_LINES) column in a separate column, like this:

```
COL1    COL2    MAX(COUNT_LINES)    SUM(MAX(COUNT_LINES))
A       B       1                   5
X       B       2                   5
X       Y       2                   5
```

But that is the part I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can you add sample data and table definition for `my_table`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid irrelevant in this particular case

Comment: Why ask the same question once again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939961/sql-to-calculate-sum-of-column-values-and-repeat-this-value-over-all-rows

Comment: Asking it more clearly this time :-)

Comment: @Shadow First of all his first query is invalid which has a non aggregated filed id in select list so that is why to get better understanding what he is trying to achieve i asked for sample data and definition

Comment: It's perfectly valid

Comment: @vdvaxel No, as per docs [12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) its invalid

Comment: @vdvaxel - adding sample data and expected result should solve most of the confusion

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - In Mysql, we can use non aggregate columns in `select` which is not part of group by. It is a valid query

Comment: @vdvaxel . . . Your question makes no sense.  Why are you choosing `id` and aggregating by `col1` and `col2`?  I would suggest that you ask another question and do a better job showing the data you have, as well as your desired results.  Why would you aggregate by `col1,col2` in a subquery, and then aggregate by the same keys in the outer query?

Comment: @Pரதீப் In older versions  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled by default, Also to choose non aggregated column the result will be indeterminate, Please refer to link in my previous comment for better understanding

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid the exact table structure is completely irrelevant, this is a sample table. There is enough sample data to understand what the OP wants. That a query in a question is not correct - well this is why there is a question.

Comment: @Shadow *There is enough sample data* this is not sample data from table its a result from query :)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid why, results are not data?

Comment: @Shadow Again, because the query is invalid, So these results makes no sense

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid again, it is expected that a query in a question is incorrect.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I have added an example with sample data and what I would like to achieve in the original post at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE for this

```
with q as
(
  SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, MAX(a.COUNT_LINES) cmax
  FROM 
    (SELECT COL1, COL2, HOUR, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_LINES
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY DAY, HOUR, COL1, COL2) a
  GROUP BY COL1, COL2
)
SELECT q.*, (SELECT SUM(q.cmax) from q)
FROM q
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8dcbce7274f5eee267905561c61ec812)

which can be rewritten (for older MySQL) as

```
SELECT q.*, 
(
  SELECT SUM(cmax) from 
  (
    SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, MAX(a.COUNT_LINES) cmax
    FROM 
    (SELECT COL1, COL2, HOUR, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_LINES
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY DAY, HOUR, COL1, COL2) a
    GROUP BY COL1, COL2  
  ) q
) as max_sum
FROM 
(
  SELECT a.COL1, a.COL2, MAX(a.COUNT_LINES) cmax
  FROM 
    (SELECT COL1, COL2, HOUR, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_LINES
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY DAY, HOUR, COL1, COL2) a
  GROUP BY COL1, COL2
) q
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6647a1e519f6bf551c3429a98c61a68e)

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem to support the WITH clause unfortunately

Comment: There is no other way to do this?

Comment: @vdvaxel no, I believe that without window functions and CTE, not

Comment: I don't see the reason of down vote on such answer, Both approaches are valid the difference is first approach will work in Mysql 8+

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COL1,Max(COUNT_ID),Sum(SUM_MAX_COUNT) FROM(
SELECT COL1,
   Count(*) AS COUNT_ID,
   (SELECT Sum(Count(*))
    FROM   TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY COL1) AS SUM_MAX_COUNT
FROM   TABLE_NAME
GROUP  BY COL1)
GROUP BY COL1;
```

Comment: There's 2 FROM statements?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give the right answer:

```
mysql-sql> select
       ...     x.col1,
       ...     x.col2,
       ...     x.max_count_lines,
       ...     y.sum_max_count_lines
       ... from
       ...     (  
       ...         select
       ...             a.col1,
       ...             a.col2,
       ...             max(a.count_lines) as max_count_lines
       ...         from 
       ...             (
       ...                 select
       ...                     col1,
       ...                     col2,
       ...                     hour,
       ...                     count(*) as count_lines
       ...                 from
       ...                     table1
       ...                 group by
       ...                     day,
       ...                     hour,
       ...                     col1,
       ...                     col2
       ...              ) a
       ...         group by
       ...              col1,
       ...              col2
       ...     ) x,
       ...     (
       ...         select
       ...             sum(max_count_lines) as sum_max_count_lines
       ...         from
       ...             (  
       ...                 select
       ...                     b.col1,
       ...                     b.col2,
       ...                     max(b.count_lines) as max_count_lines
       ...                 from 
       ...                     (
       ...                         select
       ...                             col1,
       ...                             col2,
       ...                             hour,
       ...                             count(*) as count_lines
       ...                         from
       ...                             table1
       ...                         group by
       ...                             day,
       ...                             hour,
       ...                             col1,
       ...                             col2
       ...                      ) b
       ...                 group by
       ...                      col1,
       ...                      col2
       ...             ) c
       ...     ) y;
+------+------+-----------------+---------------------+
| col1 | col2 | max_count_lines | sum_max_count_lines |
+------+------+-----------------+---------------------+
| A    | B    |               1 |                   5 |
| X    | B    |               2 |                   5 |
| X    | Y    |               2 |                   5 |
+------+------+-----------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```